# How to check if datatable has not been changed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable and I'm implementing a feature that tells if the datatable in my application has not been changed since it was loaded from the database.

For example no rows added, no rows edited, no rows deleted since it was loaded from database (I don't care about the case when the data changes in database and not reflected in my datatable)

I implemented something like this :

```
    'DataTable clean means it has not been changed
    Public ReadOnly Property DataTableClean As Boolean
        Get
            Dim Clean As Boolean = True
            For i = 0 To DataTable.Rows.Count - 1
                If DataTable.Rows(i).RowState <> DataRowState.Unchanged Then
                    Clean = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Return Clean
        End Get
    End Property
```

This code does the job but I'm not very confortable with performance in case the datatable contains big number of rows.

Does anyone know please if there is a flag somewhere that indicates whether the datatable has been changed or not ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have an example for RowChanged https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Working-with-DataTable-2ff5f158 and just slapped togeher a concrete class coupled with extension methods to make it easy to work with GetChanges https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGAgKKpqdWjiFTrJbO3P9RZSfNo which was originally done for a C# code sample. In the GetChanges project, code module ExtensionMethods.vb there is a simple example to get familiar with the extensions. If you simple review the C# version online that may help too found here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Get-changes-for-a-11413e32

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know to avoid an expensive loop and keeping track of changes to your datatable, even in case of a call to AcceptChanges, is setting up event handlers for the [RowChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and RowDeleted events.
When you receive these events you could set a class level boolean variable that keeps the Clean status.

```
Private Boolean Clean = True
Public Sub AddChangedTrackStatus(dt as DataTable)
    AddHandler dt.RowChanged, AddressOf ChangeEvent
    AddHandler dt.RowDeleted, AddressOf ChangeEvent
    Clean = True
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeEvent(sender as Object, args as DataRowChangeEventArgs)
    Clean = False
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property DataTableClean As Boolean
    Get
       Return Clean
    End Get
End Property
```

Still this has problems because here we track one table at time and if you want a general solution to track more than one table at time then you need to add some kind of collection management in this class (private list, add/remove). And do not forget to reset the Clean variable when you Update the database.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use following function 
DataTable.GetChanges

If you find changes it means it contains change so you return False otherwise True.

More detail on MSDN:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a good start. But when the AcceptChanges is called, GetChanges will return nothing, despite the fact that the changes has not been reflected in the database (no DataAdapter.Update call made), which is not what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: That's is simple but the primary function of GetChanges is to retrieve all the rows changed and this requires a loop until the end of the DataRow set. This could be less performant than the OP code that stops at the first row changed

Comment: @ThomasCarlton if your code calls AcceptChanges somewhere, also your code will not find any change